# App keeps crashing when using Google API V2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to use Google Map in my Android app using Google API V2; I tried the app on my HTC desire phone, but it keeps on crashing. I have tried changing the Project Build Target to Android 2.2 and Android 4.2, but still no luck. I have also added the android-support-v4.jar to my project. I have tried to follow these [Link](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/+AndroidDevelopers/albums/5821305124036126721?authkey=CPT52s3t7YSpowE%22%20and%20this%20link%3a%20%22https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#adding_the_api_key_to_your_application)

Here are my codes:

**googleMaps.manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.luiz.googleMaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.luiz.googleMaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.luiz.googleMaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="I have used my keys;com.luiz.googleMaps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.luiz.googleMaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SuppportMapFragment"/>
```

---

**MainActivity**

```
package com.luiz.googleMaps;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
}
```

---

**LogCat Error:**

```
12-21 06:08:30.734: D/dalvikvm(7102): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 54K, 50% free 2692K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 93ms
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102): Failed to inflate
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:213)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at com.luiz.googleMaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SuppportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     ... 19 more
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SuppportMapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.luiz.googleMaps-2.apk]
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
12-21 06:08:30.754: E/ActivityThread(7102):     ... 22 more
12-21 06:08:30.764: D/AndroidRuntime(7102): Shutting down VM
12-21 06:08:30.764: W/dalvikvm(7102): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40128560)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.luiz.googleMaps/com.luiz.googleMaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:213)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at com.luiz.googleMaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     ... 11 more
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SuppportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     ... 19 more
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SuppportMapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.luiz.googleMaps-2.apk]
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
12-21 06:08:30.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7102):     ... 22 more
12-21 06:08:36.299: I/Process(7102): Sending signal. PID: 7102 SIG: 9
12-21 06:18:46.745: D/dalvikvm(7174): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 55K, 50% free 2691K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 45ms
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174): Failed to inflate
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:213)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at com.luiz.googleMaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SuppportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     ... 19 more
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SuppportMapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.luiz.googleMaps-1.apk]
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
12-21 06:18:46.765: E/ActivityThread(7174):     ... 22 more
12-21 06:18:46.775: D/AndroidRuntime(7174): Shutting down VM
12-21 06:18:46.775: W/dalvikvm(7174): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40128560)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.luiz.googleMaps/com.luiz.googleMaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:213)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at com.luiz.googleMaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     ... 11 more
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SuppportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     ... 19 more
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SuppportMapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.luiz.googleMaps-1.apk]
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
12-21 06:18:46.775: E/AndroidRuntime(7174):     ... 22 more
12-21 06:23:46.827: I/Process(7174): Sending signal. PID: 7174 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It was not yet mentioned in any answers below, but you might as well forget about fixing this and focus on getting API v3 working instead.  On May 19, 2013 version 2 will no longer function.  See:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using MapFragment instead of using SupportMapFragment.

My main activity looks like this

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapactivity);
    this.getActionBar().setTitle("Map");

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


}
```

}

Comment: I did try using MapFragment, but the "getFragmentManager" is throwing this error "The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity".

Comment: Be sure to import: import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the `android-support-v4.jar` & `google-play-services.jar` in your application? 
If yes then just remove the fully qualified name of activity tag to as follow:

```
`<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```

Comment: this will not fix it, because when the emulator starts will no fin the MAIN Activity that needs to launch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if Google play service is available first.

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            // what you want to do
}
```